# How do I get list of id's as int using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq, ado.net, .net-4.0

I have a DataTable, say pdt, in my code. I just want to select all `table["id"]` and populate then in an integer array.

I can go ahead with a `foreach` but I am trying to learn Lambda expressions.
I can't figure out how to deal with this.

I have tried

```
List<int> Ids = pdt.Select(row => row["Id"]; return Convert.ToInt32(r));
```

and

```
int[] Ids = pdt.Select(row => row["Id"]);
```

but nothing seems to work. I am pretty sure this is a basic question, help out a newbie please.

Comment: Nowdays you can do it like   `var ids = yourObject.Select(x =>x.Id).ToList();`

Comment: This should be the answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you want an array, you need to use the `ToArray()` extension method... but you *also* want to use the [`DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable.aspx) extension method to make the data table strongly typed in terms of a `DataRow` sequence:

```
int[] ids = pdt.AsEnumerable()
               .Select(r => (int) r["Id"])
               .ToArray();
```

EDIT: As noted in abatishchev's answer, an alternative to the explicit cast here would be to use the [`Field<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx) extension method (in `DataRowExtenions`):

```
int[] ids = pdt.AsEnumerable()
               .Select(r => r.Field<int>("Id"))
               .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

Use type-safe call:

```
r.Field<string>("Id")
```

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate of that at all. That was converting a string array... this is converting the `Id` field in each row in a datatable. In particular, I don't believe your code will work, given that all we know of the input is the `pdt` variable - `r` is only introduced as a lambda expression parameter.

Comment: Why add an answer if you've already voted to close as a duplicate?

Comment: @Jon: You're right. `AsEnumerable()` + `Select()` is what OP needs

Comment: @Jon: Anyway I saw a number of simillar question, this is duplicate not of my, but of another one :)